# PrintWindow WPF / DirectX

Tags: wpf, winapi, directx

Anyone know of a way to reliably take a snapshot of a WPF window? The [PrintWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535695.aspx) api works well for "standard" win32 windows but since WPF uses DirectX, PrintWindow fails to capture an image. I think that one would need to grab the front buffer for the DirectX object associated with the window, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Just to clarify - I am looking for a solution that works like PrintWindow - i.e. I should be able to capture the screenshot from another process with just the hwnd for the WPF window.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, and I'm not sure I'm allowed to link to my blog or not, but is [this](http://www.grumpydev.com/2009/01/03/taking-wpf-screenshots/) any use?  It basically uses a RenderTargetBitmap to generate a JPG. You can use it to "screenshot" an entire window then print that.

Comment: Thanks Steve. This won't work for my case - I will update my question because it wasn't clear. Basically, I want to be able to capture this image with access to just the Hwnd and from another process.

Comment: Ah, sorry, no idea then. I've done DirecX screenshots from within the app, but never remotely. That code was originally written for remote screenshots, but it used a self hosted WCF service, which I guess is no good for you?

Answer (score 1):

This Method should help you print the entire WPF / XAML Window

```
private void PrintWindow(PrintDialog pdPrint, 
                         System.Windows.Window wWin, 
                         string sTitle, 
                         System.Windows.Thickness? thMargin)
    {
        Grid drawing_area = new Grid();
        drawing_area.Width = pdPrint.PrintableAreaWidth;
        drawing_area.Height = pdPrint.PrintableAreaHeight;

        
        Viewbox view_box = new Viewbox();
        drawing_area.Children.Add(view_box);
        view_box.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        view_box.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;

        if (thMargin == null)
        {
            view_box.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.None;
        }
        else
        {
            
            view_box.Margin = thMargin.Value;
            view_box.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.Uniform;
        }

        
        VisualBrush vis_br = new VisualBrush(wWin);

        
        System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle win_rect = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
        view_box.Child = win_rect;
        win_rect.Width = wWin.Width;
        win_rect.Height = wWin.Height;
        win_rect.Fill = vis_br;
        win_rect.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
        win_rect.BitmapEffect = new System.Windows.Media.Effects.DropShadowBitmapEffect();

        // Arrange to produce output.
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, pdPrint.PrintableAreaWidth, pdPrint.PrintableAreaHeight);
        drawing_area.Arrange(rect);

        // Print it.
        pdPrint.PrintVisual(drawing_area, sTitle);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Sean but this won't work, I need to be able to capture the image from another process using only the HWND, I don't have access to the "wWin" in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PrintDialog.PrintVisual() method.

MSDN Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printvisual.aspx

A sample: http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Reason_9._Printing.aspx